# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Is there a Dojo mobile theme for iOS7?

Tags: dojo, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I developed an app with Worklight 6.0.0.1 and submitted it to Apple's App Store, however the iPhone app is being rejected during the review process for the reason that I don't use the native feature of iOS.

I am wondering whether there is a Dojo Mobile theme for iOS 7. If not, when will it be published?

Comment: From the question it is not understood why exactly you were rejected by the App Store review process. Please edit the question with the FULL rejection message. Also note that there is no Worklight "6.0.0.2". The latest version is 6.0.0.1 iFix1.

Comment: The reason I was rejected by the App Store is that the theme of the iphone app is ios 6 feature. And I need to make the app look different between ios 6 and ios 7. So I am looking for the ios 7 theme.

Comment: Please, EDIT the question with a complete copy/paste of the rejection text. Not explanation of the text, but a copy/paste of it.

Comment: Sorry. But I think my question is that is there a theme of dojo mobile for ios 7, not why my app is rejected by the App store.

Comment: First hit at google when looking for "dojox mobile theme ios7": http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/IOS-7-theme-td3999339.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed no iOS7 theme currently available in Dojo Mobile.  The plan is to have it in the next dojo release (Q1 or Q2 2014, exact planning still to be defined).